# implode don't insert to database

Tags: php, mysqli, implode

i want to upload data by this form

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple="" />
```

i have no problem when i upload photos

bu when i insert data to database i have a problem

this is my code

```
for ($x = 0; $x<count($file ['name']); $x++){  

$imgname     = $file ['name'] [$x] ;
$imgsize     = $file['size'] [$x];
$imgtmpname  = $file['tmp_name'] [$x];
$imgtype     = $file['type'] [$x];
$size     = 6000000;
$imgtypes    = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

$new_name_time = time();
$new_name_rand = rand(0000,9999);
$new_name_md5 = md5($new_name_time);

create_image($imgtmpname, 'files/'.$new_name, $newwidth, $newheight);

$pics[$x] = $new_name;

} // end for

$newdata = (implode("','", $pics));        

$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO msgs 
(id, yourname, msgmail, msgname, msg, pics) VALUE
('', '$yourname', '$msgmail', '$msgname', '$msg', '$newdata')");

if($insert) {
echo '<div class="msgok">done</div>';
}
```

Comment: `VALUE` should be `VALUES`.

Comment: @AmalMurali It's ironically enough, hidden in the "subject".

Comment: Problem is `$newdata = (implode("','", $pics));` with `... '$msg', '$newdata')");` ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali i can't insert data

Comment: `$newdata = (implode("','", $pics));` i think problem here @AmalMurali

Comment: @user2839993: Add an `else` block with the following code: `else { die($mysqli->error) }` and tell us what error you get.

Comment: @AmalMurali i have this Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: also if id is auto increment and primary key, you cannot insert empty id

Comment: @Rajesh i have data an when i clear $newdata Does not show any problem

Comment: try replacing $newdata = (implode("','", $pics)); with $newdata = (implode(',', $pics));

Comment: When you do that implode, you get `VALUES ('', '#yourname', '$msgname', '$msg', '$pics[0]', '$pics[1]', '$pics[2]', ...)`, which is too many pics.

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows, you have to either insert them one at a time, or use implode to create multiple values lists, each with a different pic.

Comment: Where do you set `$new_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
$newdata = (implode("','", $pics));
```

with

```
$newdata = (implode(',', $pics));
```

This should work